# No Host information in dba_db_links

Tags: oracle, dblink

I'm auditing the db_links in some databases and have found a number of db_links with no host information. I checked the sys.LINK$ table and there is no host info there either.
The database links are all called LINK followed by a timestamp.
Has anyone encountered this before?

SELECT OWNER#,NAME,HOST FROM SYS.LINK$ WHERE OWNER#=234 AND NAME = 'LINK20111011104440086446000';

```
OWNER# NAME                           HOST
```

---

```
   234 LINK20111011104440086446000
```

Answer (score 2):

That link is not valid. Oracle will let you create a link with no information: `create database link testlink` will work, but without a `using` clause it doesn't do anything, it's incomplete and not yet a functioning link. If you attempt to use it, `select * from dual@testlink` you will get `"ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found"`

You should probably drop that link.